# How do you enable retina display support on Firefox?

Tags: macbook-pro, firefox

Firefox 16 does not have retina display support out of the box.

Is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Launch firefox.
Type about:config in the URL bar
Type layers.acceleration.disabled in the Search field that shows up and hit enter
Change the value to true and restart
```